# Why does the incomplete command "FINDSTR bar" break the command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

c:\users\misterfoo FINDSTR bar

I accidentally press enter while my command is incomplete. Then I have a cursor on a blank line. Whatever I type, command or gibberish, when I press enter I get a new line. CMD forgets that it runs commands and becomes a text editor.

CTRL C does nothing. I cannot backspace to erase the incomplete command, and my only option is to close and restart CMD. Pressing enter with an incomplete command should not mean I have to restart CMD.

Comment: a)ctrl-c gets out of it for me.  b)any command that you can pipe to, will wait for input from keyboard and vice versa.. e.g. try `echo ASDFbarASDF|findstr bar`  i'm not sure if they will all accept multiple lines though - perhaps.

Comment: (1) Ctrl+C works for me, too.  Also Ctrl+Z followed by Enter.  (2) @barlop: How does your (b) help the OP?

Comment: @G-Man he described some things happening, and one thing he described was a cursor on a blank line and being able to enter characters(, and in 'b', I gave some explanation for that. Giving info that can improve somebody's understanding is generally helpful. An increased understanding of what is happening is beneficial/helpful - with or without a solution.  You'd be a very poor techie if you just applied things or looked for answers without understanding or looking to understand, what was going on.

Comment: @barlop: OK, you were explaining that the `findstr bar` command wasn't hung, but was simply reading from the keyboard (and searching any typed input for the word "bar").  I see that now.  (But David said the same thing (38 seconds earlier!)  And I'm not sure your comment is worded in a way that will be comprehensible to somebody at the OP's level of understanding.  And I still don't really understand the bit about accepting multiple lines.)

Comment: @G-Man I think his was hung his ctrl-c didn't work, but that's still inexplicable,y ctrl-c didn't work for him. But part of what he described, he didn't seem to be aware was normal operation.As4 the point about multiple lines, I don't yet get it to my satisfaction either.But as a general note,it's OK to write something that is not comprehensible to the OP e.g. maybe the OP will come back in 5 years,or maybe somebody else will get it.  It's never just about the person asking..Or maybe a very curious OP might ask and ask until they understand, or maybe they won't 'cos they don't care.All is fine

Comment: @G-Man  It looks like they accept multiple lines if they read a line from stdin, in a loop, and break out of the loop when no more lines are to be read e.g. ctrl-c or ctrl-z,.  C# lets readLine() return null when no more lines are to be read.  That behaviour where he thought it looked a bit like a text editor stunned him but is normal. You might understand that as a programmer  It hanging was not normal. . Anyhow, his one hung and that's still a mystery nobody has answered

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what you asked it to do, reading its input and extracting "bar" strings from it. I'm not sure why you couldn't exit with control-C. That works for me.